# How do I stop other users launching a script?

Tags: tomcat

We have this problem where people start the tomcat server as root and that causes start up issues. We have a script and want to force system admins to start tomcat using the script which starts tomcat as webuser.

Can I modify catalina.sh or through any other mechanism for tomcat to fail at startup if the user is any other than webuser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this within a wrapper script that calls `catalina.sh`, so that future upgrades of Tomcat will not overwrite your changes.

```
if [ "$(whoami)" != "webuser" ]; then
  echo "Please start this process as 'webuser'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: +1 but do you have any suggestions on how to deal with your modified catalina.sh getting overwritten by updates of tomcat?

Comment: @fvu - not specifically, which is why I also mentioned that you can use the above snippet in a script which wraps `catalina.sh` - I'll edit to make it clear that this is the preferred option though

Comment: I added this script to my etenv,sh which is used to inject application variables and jvm settings